# How to implement a simple add-in for MS Excel on C++

Tags: c++, excel, mfc, com, atl

I need a help for implementing add-in for Excel 2010 or higher on C++, the only functionality of this add-in is renaming of current Excel sheet.

The add-in should create new custom tab on the Ribbon with name: “Test Add-in”, this tab contains group with name “My Functionality”, this group contains large button with some picture with name “Rename Current Sheet”. After clicking on the button, I should show the following dialog:
[image]

User can enter new name, click ok and after this, the name of current sheet will be changed.

I understand that I need to use `#import` directive for getting references to Office API, use `ATL` to wrap `COM` objects, `MFC` or `WTL` to create dialog, but I I'm not opposed to using the mentioned methodologies.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"simple add-in"* for Office. The task (using native code) is extremely involved, and requires intimate familiarity with COM programming. You don't *need* to use `#import`, ATL, MFC, or WTL. If in doubt, the latter will make the job harder. You need to start by understanding [COM basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx).

Comment: You do not need MFC, C++, COM, ATL and other cool things you could tag your question. All you need is to record the macro in Excel and then save this macro for "All Open Workbooks". Three is nothing here that can't be done using Excel VBA. Try it, it is very simple